# Regex shows incorrect answer

Tags: java, regex

I have a text file where it has information of a person. I have written a regex to extract age of a person ie X years Y months.

```
    String n="Mayur is  18 years 4 months old ";
    Pattern p=Pattern.compile("[\\d+\\s+years]+[\\d+\\s+months]+",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(n);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(0));
    }
```

Output i received is:

```
r 
s  18 years 4 months o
```

I did not extracted those wanted characters in the output but it is listed them.

Expected output is:

```
18 years 4 Month
```

Please not they are records with only years and some with only months.

Comment: Change `[` and `]` to `(` and `)`.

Comment: See your regex on debuggex: https://www.debuggex.com/r/H2Z7ohNROj1gmu-m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?:\\d+\\s+(?:years|months)\\s*){1,2}
```

Use this.`[]` is not what you think.Its a character class.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/uE3cC4/25

Comment: No it is not displaying anything. and m.matches() returns false

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your regex is that `[\d+\s+years]` matches any character found in the list so that's why you got `r` in the result you don't have to use brackets `[]`.

This is the Regex you need `(\\d+\\s* years\\s*)*(\\d+\\s* months)*`, use `()` for a matching group.

I changed `\\s+` to `\\s*` to make it match cases where it's written:

```
Mayur is  18years 4months old
```

Here's a **[Live DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zO4oK7/1)**

**EDIT**:

The problem of empty strings is due to to the `*`quantifier after the matching groups, I fixed it using this new Regex:

```
(\\d+\\s* years\\s*)+|(\\d+\\s* months)+
```

See the **[DEMO here](https://regex101.com/r/zO4oK7/3)**

Comment: I seen an ambiguity on running this expression m.matched returns false but  group(0)  returns 18 years  4 months. I have mentioned the file might have years alone or months alone. Above expression fails in that case.

Comment: @MohanRaj Ah ok I missed that , take a look I changed the Regex.

Comment: @MohanRaj the answer you accepted will accept empty string as well.Do you want that ?

Comment: Vks could you explain with example. I tried with empty string. No result were displayed.

Comment: @MohanRaj https://regex101.com/r/zO4oK7/2 see the groups which ar ebeing marked.Also empty string are being marked at the end

Comment: Sorry Vks . I did not understand the empty strings you are talking about here. As i  explained above i tested with the empty string but  regex provided did not accept. When i gave empty string in the link you have provide it shows result as follows No match groups were extracted.
This means that your pattern matches but there were no (capturing (groups)) in it that matched anything in the subject string. Are you talking about the statement pattern matches in this statement??

Comment: Chsdk  regex provided results true for empty string. VKS pointed that.

Comment: @MohanRaj It was a quantifier problem, using `*`was a bad idea I fixed it, here's the new Regex `(\\d+\\s* years\\s*)+|(\\d+\\s* months)+`, see my EDIT.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String n="Mayur is  18 years 4 months old ";
Pattern p=Pattern.compile("([0-9]+) years ([0-9]+) months",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(n);
while (m.find()) {
    String years = m.group(1);
    String months = m.group(2);
    System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
```

Using "0" as group you can get the whole expression. Otherwise using 1 or 2 you can get the values.